# How do I configure users on my ubuntu system without shell and execute only one command?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

I need to build a Ubuntu server where users will be logged in but I dont want them to give a shell access. As soon as the user logs in one custom command will be executed and it will be allow certain options.

I do not allow user to log in on shell or run any other commands.

Can you please suggest?

TIA
Blaon R

Comment: please explain more about the command you need to be executed.

Comment: This is a custom bash script that I am going to write with case/esac stattement. May be by now we can take this script
```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Tell me your name: "
read resp
echo $resp
```

Comment: you just need to run the command ? no need to login ?

Comment: That is correct - I mean once user logs in directly that command will be executed and option will be given. I do not want any shell access to be given for any user

Answer (score 0):

you just create your script as you said and place it in the user's home directory path(create the user with adduser command).

So for you case I written your script in shell-command.sh file.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Tell me your name: "
read resp
echo $resp
```

make the script executable.

```
 chmod a+x shell-command.sh
```

Open the /etc/passwd file and edit your desired user shell after his/her home directory path as below.

```
testuser:x:1001:1001:test user,,,:/home/testuser:/home/testuser/shell-command.sh
```

Done.

Comment: Thats great - Ididnt know that- Thanks though let me test it out

Comment: Well this works but output does not stay on console. As soon as the command is entered the output disappears

Comment: what do you mean by saying console? are sshing to the remote server? or what ?